# arXiv: post supplementary files using external document and xr

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, arxiv

I have two documents in LaTeX, one called main.tex and the other supplement.tex. They are both linked together by the xr package and compile without error. (They have to be compiled in the order: pdflatex on main followed by pdflatex on the supplement and then pdflatex on the main again to complete the cross-referencing. Is there a way to put this on arXiv and letting the compiler there know that pdflatex has to run a few times on each docment? Many thanks! Should one put up the .aux files also in that case?

Comment: Hi, is there a possibility that you can give us an example how cross-referencing each other (main.tex and supplement.tex) works using xr package? I would like submit at the PRL, but struggling with this cross-referencing.

Answer (score 15):

You can workaround a problem. Take your file.aux, create xx.tex and upload it to arxiv along with your latex file. the xx.tex is:

```
\begin{filecontents}{file.aux}
The content of file.aux
\end{filecontents}
```

In your latex file add (on top)
\usepackage{filecontents}

and before \end{document} add

```
\makeatletter\@input{xx.tex}\makeatother
```

This way your latex file will create the file.aux that you can use with xr and \externaldocument

Comment: It works! I Just add a clarification, since I was a bit confused at first. Here `file.aux` refers to the `main.aux` in the question, and `your latex file` is the `supplement.tex`. So you take the generated aux file from your main tex file and add it to the supplement.

Comment: This trick is really good and applicable to any other submission files, e.g., file.toc (for Table of Contents). Some packages (e.g., pagesel) forces ArXiv NOT to generate the required files like .aux, .toc, etc.

Comment: What about `xx.tex`. Can this be anything, or does it specifically need to be `xx.tex`? What if you also reference the main document in supplemental info?

Comment: The answer here does indeed work, but if you have a lot of `aux` files or they are very long, then it is a bit annoying to implement. Generally you shouldn't be copy+pasting lots of information. It's better if you can just reference it. I took the ideas from this answer and made it, in my view, a bit nicer to implement. Certainly it was nicer for me, as I had _five_ papers all referencing each other! I didn't want to be copy+pasting all these `.aux` files all the time. I've made my method into another answer on this question. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592673/81928

Comment: @Sam-OT I mean internal hyperlinks (e.g. `[1]` takes you to Ref 1, `Section 1.1` takes you to Section 1.1, etc.). I was having trouble with this answer (maybe I implemented it incorrectly, or maybe it's because I'm using `zref` and `\zexternaldocument*{}`), so tried I this [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514103/224861), but ran into the issue of all hyperlinks being wiped from the document (including URLs). Thanks for the response!

Comment: Came back to this, and tried this specifically, but ran into the same issue with hyperlinks not functioning properly (e.g. reference to `Figure 1` in main document isn't clickable at all). Again, not referring to cross-document hyperlinking, just within-document. URLs get mangled when they go across two lines to boot. Guess I'll be defaulting back to chemRxiv, though would still really like to be able to submit to arXiv normally. @SamOT would love to hear if you come across any updates/fixes for this. Thanks also for the responses last year.

Comment: @Sterling Only just seen this! I actually posted an answer on this a while ago, explaining how I do it. It's below this one when ordered by votes, but it is, in my view, simpler. Let me know if you have any issues with that, commenting on that answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I would upload the compiled `supplement.pdf`, and `supplement.aux` with `main.tex` so the arXiv compiler can extract all the labels used in `supplement.tex` (via [`xr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr)) when building `main.tex`, that should compile fine.

However I really would suggest including the supplementary in the main PDF (e.g. combining the tex sources or appending `supplement.pdf` using [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)) as finding supplementary through downloading the source is a pain and can leave the supplement's existence poorly advertised.

Comment: I tried uploading supplement.aux and main.aux since both documents cross-reference each other, but to no avail.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how pdfpages works but not sure that the cross-referencing can work as is being suggested. Note that both main.tex and supplement.tex reference each other and it works very well for my purposes.

Comment: The arXiv wants a single file to compile to produce the paper, anything else should be included as an [ancilliary file](https://arxiv.org/help/ancillary_files) so I am suggesting upload the pre-compiled `supplement.pdf` and as long as `supplement.aux` is bundled with `main.tex` all references should appear correctly in the produced `main.pdf`.  Are you looking for hyperlinking to work?  This would be much more of a problem.

Comment: ArXiv now seems to complains about uploading `.aux` files that have a corresponding `.tex` file

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference (and because I was proud of myself for finding this), I found another way taking inspiration from [Overleaf's instructions to use xr](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf). This can equally be achieved by adding the following to the head of your main tex file:

```
\usepackage{xr}   
% The following is to make it work on Arxiv. The trick is to include the
% build/*.aux files in the zip, they are then hidden to Arxiv which does not
% delete them.
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{ % argument=file name and extension
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[3][SI]{%
  \externaldocument[#1]{#2/#3}%
    \addFileDependency{#3.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#2/#3.aux}%
}
% Invoke \externaldocument with an additional parameter setting
% the directory where you will leave your .aux file (build/ here)
\myexternaldocument[SI]{build}{SI-filename}
```

and including the directory where you left your .aux file (here `build/`) when you upload files during your submission.

---

For clarity, here's a **MWE**: imagine you have two files, a main text (`main.tex`) and supplementary text (`supp.tex`), that you want to cross-reference. What you want to upload to arXiv is a zip with the following file structure:

```
├── main.tex
├── supp.tex
├── style.sty
├── build
│   ├── main.aux
│   ├── supp.aux
```

You can either manually move the .aux files resulting from the compilations in a build/ directory, or, as I do, configure this directory as the output directory of your compilation (using `latexmk`, providing the option `-outdir=build`, or for `pdflatex`, `-output-directory=build/`).

Now here's the content of each .tex and .sty files:

`style.sty`

```
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{ % argument=file name and extension
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[3][SI]{%
  \externaldocument[#1]{#2/#3}%
  \addFileDependency{#3.tex}%
  \addFileDependency{#2/#3.aux}%
}
```

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{style}
\myexternaldocument[SI]{build}{supp}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{sec:mainsec}

See \ref{SIsec:sec1}

\end{document}
```

`supp.tex`

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{style}
\myexternaldocument[M]{build}{main}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{sec:sec1}

See \ref{Msec:mainsec}

\end{document}
```

And in the output PDFs, you should have "See S1" appearing in the main text, and "See I" in the supplementary.

Comment: had trouble getting this to work, though this seems like a nice option. Do you mind providing a full MWE? In particular, getting a `Undefined control sequence.` which seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Also, I needed to remove `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding if `SI` from `\myexternaldocument[SI]` is meant to correspond to a certain filename or is supposed to be left as `SI`. Could you clarify?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a MWE, let me know if you still get errors. Regarding `SI`, it's just the standard option from the `xr` package (see its CTAN page), providing a prefix for the labels of the other document, which is recommendable for clarity, and to avoid name conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation: I had give papers in total, all referencing each other! I uploaded them all to arXiv on the same day. For simplicity, let's pretend I just had two.
I had the following code on my preamble.

```
\usepackage{xr}
%\externaldocument{Paper1}
\externaldocument{Paper2}
```

Here I assume we're working in `Paper1` so I commented it out because you don't need to self-reference with `xr`. Indeed, if you do, then it will give you `multiple defined labels` warnings. Comment out the second line in `Paper2`.

*Very importantly, you must make sure that labels are referenced in a unique way across all documents.* Eg, don't use `\ref{sec:intro}`. I used `\label{sec-p1:intro}` and `\label{sec-p2:intro}`. I believe `xr` package has an optional arugument. I am not sure of the exact details, but if you write something like `\externaldocument[p2:]{Paper2}` then any label `label` from `Paper2` will be imported as `p2:label`. Personally I preferred writing in the paper number manually, but either option is fine.

The following is *my understanding* of what happens. It might not be 100% accurate.

- If the current document is `Paper1.tex`, then latex creates `Paper1.aux` with all the label references. This file is used for the cross-references. Eg, if you type `\ref{label}` then it looks in `Paper1.aux` for the label `label` and, if it exists, prints out the appropriate thing.
- The `xr` package makes latex look not just in `doc.aux` but in all the referenced documents. So above it will look in both of `Paper1.aux` and `Paper2.aux`.
- Importantly, the `xr` package *does not* create `Paper2.aux`. We are running latex on `Paper1.tex`, so it only changes `Paper1.???`.

Now I describe how to do the arXiv submission.

- Make a new folder, `arXiv_Submission_Paper1` and move your `Paper1.tex` file to this folder, along with anything else you need to compile---pictures, premable, etc.
- Incidentally, it is good practice to make a full copy of your submission and place it in a folder which you don't edit. This way you can see in the future exactly what you uploaded.
- Also, place `Paper2.aux` in this folder. You don't need `Paper2.tex`---you aren't going to compile that. You *only* need the `.aux` file.
- Now just upload `Paper1`, uploading `Paper1.tex` *and* `Paper2.aux`, along with anything else you may need! The `xr` package reads the `Paper2.aux` file exactly as you want it to.
- Swap the numbers `1` and `2` to do the same for `Paper2`.

This can easily be extended to more papers by just uploading more `.aux` files. If you have lots, you could create a subfolder called `aux_files` and use `\externaldocument{aux_files/paper#}`.

Alternatively, you can just merge all the other `.aux` files, eg `Paper1.aux`, `Paper2.aux`, `Paper3.aux`, `Paper4.aux` and `Paper5.aux` into `aux_all.aux`. You then just use `\externaldocument{aux_all}`. They might seem scary because of the `.aux` file extension. But they're just plain text files. You can edit them with `Notepad`, for example. Make sure to include a linebreak at the end of each file! You will get `multiple defined labels` warnings if you include `Paper1.aux`. It's up to you whether you are happy with this warning---it is only a *warning* and will not stop tex from running.

I can confirm that this worked on arXiv both in November 2019 (first upload) and in February 2021 (revision). The arXiv system changed *significantly* between these two times. arXiv used to just run latex *once*. This is one reason why you need to upload a `.bbl` file, rather than the `.bib`. These days arXiv will run latex many times. The above method worked, unchanged, both times.

Answer (score 2):

the xr package (and packages like it, such as xref that rely on having an external aux file present) don't work in arXiv's autotex engine. You'll need to re-work you citations between the two documents to not be cross-referenced from the same aux file.

Answer (score 0):

I messaged both arXiv and Overleaf directly, as the previous answers still led to wiping out all hyperlinks when used with `zref` and `\zexternaldocument*{}`. arXiv suggested that I could build a PDF directly and that an exception could be issued. Overleaf replied that they weren't aware of any additional workarounds. For now, I've switched to an alternative preprint server (in my case, ChemRxiv), although may consider trying either to build my own PDF or making an arXiv-specific `.tex` file with both main and supplementary in a single document.

My message to arXiv:

> I've come to the same problem several times over the last year or so.
> I understand that "packages such as xr and xref that rely on the
> \externaldocument command will not work in arXiv."
> (https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#bibtex). It also mentions: "Instead
> we require that you update your .bbl files to include the appropriate
> references for both documents." However, I'm not really sure how to
> implement this, since I'm running into issues with cross-referencing
> Figures/Tables/etc. rather than citations. I've tried workarounds such
> as described in
> [arXiv: post supplementary files using external document and xr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399065/arxiv-post-supplementary-files-using-external-document-and-xr/590837#590837),
> but even if I get the labels to display properly, then within-document
> hyperlinks don't seem to work at all. A reference to Figure 1 in the
> main text isn't actually hyperlinked at all.

arXiv Response:

> Thank you for your question. The merging of two documents in arXiv is
> accomplished via the pdfpages package. This behavior is detailed in
> the pdfpages manual (presently on page 2):
>
> [1]http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page=2
>
> "Links and other interactive features of PDF documents When including
> pages of a PDF only the so called content stream of these pages is
> copied but no links. Up to now there are no TeX-engines (pdfTeX,
> XeTeX, ...) available that can copy links or other interactive
> features of a PDF document, too. Thus, all kinds of links will get
> lost during inclusion."
>
> You are welcome to attempt to build your own pdf using the method that
> they suggest (the experimental pax package, see details at the above
> link), and then upload it into a replacement if having a single
> clickable document is important to you. An alternative method that
> could produce working links is to use GhostScript: gs
> -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=combined.pdf  main.pdf supp.pdf
>
> Please be sure to contact us with the submit-id so that we can issue
> an exception for your pdf.