# Handling main text and supplementary information crossreferencing each other on arXiv

Tags: arxiv, xr

A typical example when writing a paper is that you have a main document `main.tex` and a document containing supplementary information `si.tex`.
Both documents are stand-alone in the sense that they compile into separate documents with separate bibliographies, however one of or both document(s) may explicitly reference sections of the other.

This is often done by including something similar to

```
\usepackage{xr}
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
    \externaldocument{#1}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}

\myexternaldocument{si}
```

to `main.tex` and/or vice versa.

The problem arises from how arXiv processes your file submissions. All `.tex` files are compiled in alphabetical order, and each will have the corresponding `.aux` and `.pdf` files deleted beforehand. This order can be changed by renaming files or by specifying the toplevel file in `00README.XXX` as described [here](https://arxiv.org/help/00README). But the problem remains that arXiv deletes the `.aux` files corresponding to any `.tex` files that will be compiled. How is the best way to solve this?

Comment: [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399065/arxiv-post-supplementary-files-using-external-document-and-xr)

Comment: Could you please gimme a simple example how this cross-referencing for each other works? I couldn't figure this out for PRL submission.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I've come up with that doesn't require changing anything in your `.tex` files is to compile your two documents yourself before uploading, then rename your two `.tex` files. Since arXiv only deletes `.aux` files that correspond to a `.tex` file, this effectively removes the cross-dependency between the files.

Say that both `main.tex` and `si.tex` reference each other. After compiling, validating that everything looks alright and renaming the `.tex` files you should be left with a set of temporary files as well as

```
main_renamed.tex
main.aux
si_renamed.tex
si.aux
```

Once upload on arXiv, `main_renamed.tex` will be compiled first and since `si.aux` are not deleted, the references should compile successfully. Afterwards `si_renamed.tex` will be compiled and since `main.aux` exists, the references should compile successfully. Since `main_renamed.tex` was compiled before `si_renamed.tex`, that is the order the text will appear in the final pdf document.

Comment: One issue I encountered by doing this was that the hyperlinks (hyperref package) weren't working anymore. They were formatted correctly, but not clickable. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2653663 Was stuck on this for hours (until trying this answer). Needed to rename other dependency files (`.glo`, `.bbl`, etc.), but seemed to work. No hyperlinks and not sure why (note: I had turned off ArXiv's `HyperTeX` due to a hyperref conflict), but at least the formatting is correct and I can submit! (but ditto on getting hyperlinks to work @Ben)